# TypeError: inner is not a function

Tags: javascript

In the below code snippet, why I am getting the error inner is not a function?

```js
var inner = 10;

function inner() {
  console.log("Hey type", typeof inner);
}
inner()
```

Comment: the variable "inner" and function "inner" should not share the same name.

By the time you call inner() it has changes from int to function

Comment: @DedanIrungu That's just wrong. If `inner` was a function, like you say, there wouldn't be an error ...

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way hoisting works in javascript the `inner` **function declaration** is fully declared (and callable) **before** the `inner`-variable gets assigned the number value. So you are actually overriding the inner function with a number in line 1.

Using a **function expression** instead will output the result `function`. I guess that is what you expected.

```js
var inner = 10;

var inner = function() {
  console.log("Hey type", typeof inner);
}
inner()
```